# Would it make sense to classify pdf documents based on their structure with RNNs?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, text-mining, recurrent-neural-network

I am wondering if using RNNs to classify pdf documents for types of documents (i.e. scientific papers, books, reports, etc) based on the structural components like the text boxes and image boxes and their coordinates will make sense.

Will the sequential order of the components make a good model of the type of document or are pdf files structure too messy for that?

If you think not what would it be the best approach to use this structural info to classify the documents or will image classification approaches work better?

Comment: The abstract alone should have enough information for most documents. It often will mention "this study" or "in this book"

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this was achievable with even simpler ML algorithms (non-neural networks), or solution not using ML would have pretty good performance (e.g. I'd start with a rule that if the first page contains the word "Abstract" classify it as a scientific paper and would expect reasonable performance on the rule alone).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be much easier to convert each page to image and train CNN that classify one page from the book, paper, etc. Then you can try to propagate each page from the book through the CNN and aggregate obtained results for each page. You can use different aggregation methods. For instance, you can average all probability distribution vectors and choose classes that has highest probability. Or you can find class that appears more often after classifying each page. For instance, if book has 10 pages and 8 of the classified as a book and 2 of them classified as a report then you classify it as a book.

Another idea is to classify only first page, might be quite useful prediction feature. Or during the aggregation you can just give higher weight for the first page (make it more important than other page).

There are some many possibilities...

I think it would be so much complicated to get it work with RNN that has an input raw PDF structure. I don't suggest even trying it. I think you can achieve pretty good results with CNN per each page separately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about running an experiment on your idea's?

The text in the pdf should be a good indicator of the type; given that the search type was defined by an expert and tested.

A Radial Basis Function Network may be useful in this case.

Most of the work has already been done in the area of search and classification and also in the area of parsing the information (Text) from a pdf(s).

The network work would be an experiment. Eg training the network and then testing it does what you want it to.

Have you thought about

1. Looking for commonality (Term(s)) in "Like" documents. Then encode as a query or search string. NB Best done by an expert in the given field. EG A biology expert classified these documents as a good representation of document domain etc.
2. Look into the documents for "Like document term(s)" (Eg Parsing the documents with a "query" made of like term(s))
3. Mark the documents as a "Type" and you could "weight" them on the strength of match to the query.
4. The query (encoded search string Eg The term biology has a binary code) and the document encoding (similar to query) could be compared.
5. The network could be trained with pairs of encoded queries and encoded documents classification strings.
6. Once the network is trained it could be used to find similar documents.

NB Although the query and document signature may start as binary the output from the network may not be.

All the best with your work.